# Is there an equivilent of jQTouch that covers iPhone, Android, WebOS and Blackberry OS?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, blackberry, webos

I am about to start writing a web app for the latest smartphones using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript. I don’t need a framework so much as a library like jQuery.

I looked at jQTouch which is great for iPhone and apparently has support coming for Android too but I am looking to cover Blackberry device Software v4.6 upwards and WebOS 5 as well.

Does anyone have any ideas of alternatives to jQTouch or experience using jQTouch with Android's native browser, Blackberry's browser or WebOS native browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you probably have to use jQuery. In the beginning of October, the jQuery community will release a jQuery Mobile Version, where you can use all the advantages of jQuery within almost every mobile browser.
Check their site out: http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Great. I'll check this out - might posibly be able to delay enough to use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/) is a possible alternative, but I have no idea how well it works on BB and WebOS. I'm afraid that you won't find something that works well with BB, since they have switched to a Webkit based browser only recently.

Answer (score 1):

I did a project for Android and iPhone using jQTouch. There were times when I had to fiddle with the code to get it working correctly but as a whole I found that almost everything worked on iPhone and Android. Where I started having problems was that the Android browser doesn't have nearly as much support for CSS3/HTML5 (especially with animations) and the app ran much slower on android as the browser doesn't have hardware accelerated graphics. This was a while ago so hopefully it has matured a bit now.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap seems to be a reasonable cross-platform framework that supports encapsulating web app type development into an iPhone/iOS app, as well seeming to support some of the other platforms you asked about (but I have tried it on those).

http://www.phonegap.com/